# Which meta site should I post on?

Tags: support, meta, per-site-meta

Every Stack Exchange 2.0 site has a meta. So many metas! Which one should I post my bug report, feature request, or discussion in?

Comment: @juergend Gah... I only searched under [[meta-tag:faq-proposed]]...

Comment: I only had a look at the right of this page :) 4th related question. Before posting someting the duplicate finder under the question title offers most of the time a pretty good selection of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Quick cheat sheet:

- **Is the bug, feature, or discussion relevant to *a lot* of Stack Exchange?**

  If yes, post it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). <sub>Note that Meta SE doesn't exist yet; use Meta Stack Overflow instead until it's launched.</sub>

  For example, if the icons on the topbar are broken in some way, this is a network-wide bug (as the topbar appears all across the network), and should be posted on Meta SE.
- **Is the bug, feature, or discussion relevant to *only one* SE community?**

  If yes, it should go on that site's meta. Some notes:

  - Area 51 does actually have a meta; post on Area 51 Discuss with the [area51-meta] tag. The thing is, [area51-meta] is where posts go to die, so the majority of the community won't get too annoyed if you post on Meta SE with [area51](/questions/tagged/area51) instead.
  - Stack Apps doesn't have a meta. Meta-discussion is acceptable on the main site; if that feels awkward to you, post on Meta SE with [stackapps](/questions/tagged/stackapps) instead. We don't mind much.
  - There are a few miscellaneous locations (like [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) and [the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) that don't have their own metas; again, post on Meta SE using [stackexchange.com](/questions/tagged/stackexchange.com), [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer), or whatever tag's relevant.
- **Is the bug, feature, or discussion relevant to *all beta sites*?**

  If yes, Meta SE is the place. Use [beta-sites](/questions/tagged/beta-sites).

End of cheat sheet.

If you got here without finding your answer, whatever-it-is is applicable to more than one site, but not all that many of them. This is the grey area - there's no real policy on what to do. Some suggestions:

- If there's a site that is most affected, post on its meta.
- If you tend to hang around Meta SE, post there.
- If in doubt, post on the affected site you spend the most time on/otherwise feel most comfortable on.

But above all:

## Don't worry too much.

Posts can be freely migrated between metas by anyone with a ♦, so there's no lasting stigma about posting in the "wrong" place. Nobody will remember you as "that guy who posted a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) on the wrong meta", so **don't lose any sleep over it.**

Comment: This is not correct, you can post issues affecting all sites on any per-site meta you want. If a user is only active on one site, they don't even have to know about the existence of MSO, they can post about any issue on their per-site meta.

Comment: It also tells people use use a Meta SE site that will perpetually be 6 to 8 weeks away from being implemented. :P

Comment: @Mad they can, but its *better* if they are posted here

Comment: @RichardTingle You can check the proposed duplicate for an answer by Rebecca Chernoff that shows just how strong the reaction from the community team is if anyone suggests that a question should be asked on MSO instead.

Comment: @Mad doesn't seem to dispute this. "Fine" means acceptable.  Not optimal.  If someone **actually asked you** "should I post this on the main meta or any child meta" would you honestly say "choose one at random"

Comment: @RichardTingle The answer is "post on the site you're more comfortable with", unless you actually need the bigger exposure you get on MSO it doesn't really make much of a difference.

Comment: @Mad And you'll need that bigger exposure for example for getting community concensus on a feature request that affects all sites